# Одно событие в сутки

Tags: javascript

Есть некое событие, допустим всплывающее окно, как сделать так, чтобы оно всплывало для каждого пользователя 1 раз за сутки?

Не разу не работал с cookie, хочу сделать примерно следующее:

```
if(event.pageY < 2 && event.pageX > 1300){
            if(cookieSet == null){
                var cookieSet = $.cookie("popupcookie", { expires: 1 });
                $('#popup').show();
                $('#pDis').addClass('parentDisable');
            }else{
                    return; // esli estj cookie
            }


    }
```

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан `if(cookieSet == null){` это вы так наличие куки проверяете? Почитайте документацию о том, как получать её. У вас на странице никогда не будет `cookieSet`